# pythontex on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, python, pygments

After installing the package `pythontex` via `latex pythontex.ins`, I tried the following example to test it:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{pythontex}  
\listfiles  
\begin{document}
\begin{pycode}  
print "Hello \Latex "
\end{pycode}  
\end{document}
```

First step was `pdflatex PythonExample1.tex` which I got the following message:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
restricted \write18 enabled.entering extended mode
(./PythonExample1.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 4 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty)     (./pythontex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline   fix 
<2008/02/07> (tvz) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-  dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfopts/pgfopts.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/newfloat.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/currfile/currfile.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty))
(./PythonExample1.aux) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)))
No file pythontex-files-PythonExample1/PythonExample1.pytxmcr.
Run PythonTeX to create it.
(./PythonExample1.aux)

*File List*
article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
pythontex.sty    2014/07/17 Version\unhbox\voidb@x \penalty \@M \ {}0.14 
fancyvrb.sty    2008/02/07
keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
xstring.sty    2013/10/13  v1.7c  String manipulations (C Tellechea)
pgfopts.sty    2011/06/02 v2.1 LaTeX package options with pgfkeys
pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
newfloat.sty    2013/05/11 v1.1-91 Defining new floating environments (AR)
currfile.sty    2013/02/01 v0.7b Provides the file path elements of the   current
input file
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
upquote.sty    2012/04/19 v1.3 upright-quote and grave-accent glyphs in  verbat
im
xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
supp-pdf.mkii
***********

)
No pages of output.
Transcript written on PythonExample1.log.
```

After that was `pythontex PythonExample1.tex` to get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pythontex", line 42, in <module>
import pythontex2 as pythontex
File "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/pythontex/pythontex2.py", line  61, in <module>
from pygments.styles import get_all_styles
ImportError: No module named pygments.styles
```

which is because that pygments is not installed. After installing it I get the following error message

```
----  Messages for py:default:default  ----
* PythonTeX stderr - error on line 11:
File "<outputdir>/py_default_default.py", line 50
print "Hello \Latex"
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

--------------------------------------------------
PythonTeX:  PythonExample1 - 1 error(s), 1 warning(s)
```

Finally, even if I try `pdflatex PythonExample.tex` again, no pdf file will be generated. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 2.7.6 Any help!

Comment: What version of Pygments do you have? You can probably get this by running `pygmentize -V` at the command prompt.

Comment: @G.Poore Opps, it is not installed. I just installed and edit the post. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are using `print` as a statement, so you need

```
\usepackage[pyfuture=none]{pythontex}
```

By default, several things are imported from `__future__` (`absolute_import`, `division`, `print_function`); this disables the automatic import.  Also, you will want to use a raw string or escape the backslash (`\\LaTeX`)

Alternatively, you could use `print("Hello \\LaTeX")`.